# JQuery 2.2.0 error

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I have a page that is generated by CakePHP 3. This is the basic structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?= $this->Html->charset() ?>
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
        <title>
            Delta BEC |
            <?= $this->fetch('title') ?>
        </title>
        <?= $this->Html->meta('icon') ?>

        <?= $this->Html->css('bootstrap.min') ?>
        <?= $this->Html->css('font-awesome.min') ?>
        <?= $this->Html->css('custom') ?>

        <?= $this->fetch('meta') ?>
        <?= $this->fetch('css') ?>
        <?= $this->fetch('script') ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <?= $this->Flash->render() ?>
            <?= $this->fetch('content') ?>
        </div>

        <?php $this->Html->script('../plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.2.0.min.js'); ?>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
        </script>
        <?php $this->Html->script('bootstrap.min.js'); ?>
        <?php $this->Html->script('app.min.js'); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Looking at it I'm not seeing anything wrong, but I am getting these errors though:

```
jquery-ui.min.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(anonymous function) @ jquery-ui.min.js:6(anonymous function) @ jquery-ui.min.js:6
login:69 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

What am I missing?

Comment: And that's what happens when you pull an all nighter. Thanks @Stryner!

Comment: I'm not very skilled in PHP, so I wasn't sure. I added it as an answer now though.

Comment: use 'echo' in  your script tag  like         <?php echo  $this->Html->script('../plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.2.0.min.js'); ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not outputting the scripts.

```
<?= $this->fetch('script') ?>
  ^-- Implied echo

<?php $this->Html->script('../plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.2.0.min.js'); ?>
  ^-- No implied echo => not included in resposne
```